# Проблема с разверткой приложения на Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

Запускаю на *Tomcat*, *NetBeans* только скачал, `Java EE`.

```
NetBeans: Deploying on Apache Tomcat 8.0.15.0
    profile mode: false
    debug mode: false
    force redeploy: true
Отмена развертывания...
undeploy?path=/calories-tracker
OK - Undeployed application at context path /calories-tracker
Развертывание на месте на C:\JavaLesson\HelloSpring\target\calories-tracker
deploy?config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2FTimur%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2Fcontext6254289419016115778.xml&path=/calories-tracker
FAIL - Deployed application at context path /calories-tracker but context failed to start

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private calories.tracker.app.security.SecurityUserDetailsService calories.tracker.config.root.AppSecurityConfig.userDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityUserDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private calories.tracker.app.dao.UserRepository calories.tracker.app.security.SecurityUserDetailsService.userRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityUserDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private calories.tracker.app.dao.UserRepository calories.tracker.app.security.SecurityUserDetailsService.userRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private calories.tracker.app.dao.UserRepository calories.tracker.app.security.SecurityUserDetailsService.userRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appSecurityConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private calories.tracker.app.security.SecurityUserDetailsService calories.tracker.config.root.AppSecurityConfig.userDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityUserDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private calories.tracker.app.dao.UserRepository calories.tracker.app.security.SecurityUserDetailsService.userRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private calories.tracker.app.security.SecurityUserDetailsService calories.tracker.config.root.AppSecurityConfig.userDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityUserDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private calories.tracker.app.dao.UserRepository calories.tracker.app.security.SecurityUserDetailsService.userRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityUserDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private calories.tracker.app.dao.UserRepository calories.tracker.app.security.SecurityUserDetailsService.userRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private calories.tracker.app.dao.UserRepository calories.tracker.app.security.SecurityUserDetailsService.userRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined
```

И в конце:

```
28-Oct-2015 21:54:45.196 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Error listenerStart
28-Oct-2015 21:54:45.197 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/calories-tracker] startup failed due to previous errors
```

**Обновление**

web.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
        "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
        "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>

    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/resources/calories-tracker.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>


</web-app>
```

А вот что было относительно него при build'е:

> Warning: selected war files include a WEB-INF/web.xml which will be
>   ignored  (webxml attribute is missing from war task, or ignoreWebxml
>   attribute is specified as 'true')

Comment: Я никогда не работал в NetBeans, но думаю проблема можно найти в логах томката.

Comment: Попробуйте собрать в NetBeans и задеплоить руками.

Comment: Тогда встречный вопрос - где их можно посмотреть (только начал изучать Java). Просто build собирается успешно.

Comment: @TimurMusharapov %Tomcat_dir%\logs, смотрите логи за текущее число.

Comment: покажите `web.xml`

Comment: Папка с логами Томката оказалась абсолютно пустой.

Comment: web.xml поправил, ошибка все равно сохраняется.

Comment: Внес в основной текст правки о возникающих ошибках.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка скорее всего связана с тем, что `Spring` не может найт bean нужного типа.

Bean с типом `javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory` не был найден в контексте `Spring` (при создании bean с именем `userRepository`).

Это можно понять, если прочитать сообщение об ошибке:

```
Caused by: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
    Could not autowire field: 
    private calories.tracker.app.security.SecurityUserDetailsService calories.tracker.config.root.AppSecurityConfig.userDetailsService; 
nested exception is 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
    Error creating bean with name 'securityUserDetailsService': 
    Injection of autowired dependencies failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
    Could not autowire field: private calories.tracker.app.dao.UserRepository 
    calories.tracker.app.security.SecurityUserDetailsService.userRepository; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
    Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': 
    Injection of persistence dependencies failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
    No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined
```

Comment: Скажите, а как это можно поправить?

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйта, код класса `calories.tracker.app.security.SecurityUserDetailsService.userRepository`. А так же определение ваших бинов. Или же приведите ссылку на проект, если он в открытом доступе.